# Guardar Archivo txt en ruta elegida por el usuario en python

Tags: python, guardar

Tengo un programa en Python, el cual al terminar crea un reporte en txt . Con el método filedialog.asksaveasfilename solicito que se abra un cuadro de dialogo para guardar como, de modo que el usuario teclee el nombre y seleccione del cuadro de dialogo la ruta en la que quiere guardar. Sin embargo, lo que obtengo como resultado es que el archivo sí se guarda con el nombre que el usuario le indica pero por defalut siempre lo guarda en la misma carpeta, la cual es siempre la carpeta en la cual estoy desarrollando el código. Igualmente cuando lo convierto en ejecutable usando pyinstaller, se crea un ejecutable y el reporte ahora lo guardará siempre en la carpeta donde se encuentre alojado el ejecutable. Aquí el código que estoy empleando

```
archivo_OAG=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",filetypes=[('text file','*.txt')],defaultextension='.txt') # cuadro de dialogo salvar como
nombre_arch=os.path.basename(archivo_OAG) # obtención de la ruta del archivo guardado
print(os.path.basename(archivo_OAG))

file=open(nombre_arch, 'w') 
file.write("REPORTE DE PROGRAMA, 2022" + os.linesep)
file.close()
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Sin embargo, os.path.basename te devuelve el nombre del archivo sin el path. Por ejemplo si tienes c:/windows/hola.txt os.path.basename devuelve hola.txt. quiza te conviene quitar el os.path.basename asi el archivo se guarda en el directorio indicado por el usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El basename de **la ruta de un archivo** es el **nombre del archivo**.
Ejemplo:

```py
ruta= r"C:\Users\user\Pictures\imagen.png"

os.path.basename(ruta) # "imagen.png"
os.path.dirname(ruta) # "C:\Users\user\Pictures"
```

Usa el valor que te devuelve el método **filedialog.asksaveasfilename()**.

Cambia esto:

```py
file=open(nombre_arch, 'w')
```

por esto:

```py
file=open(archivo_OAG, 'w')
```

Comment: Gracias, tenias toda la razón